# LS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file pragma procedure form

Tags: database, compiler-errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_package AS
TYPE emp_data_type IS RECORD (
    emp_number NUMBER,
    hire_date  VARCHAR2(12),
    emp_name   VARCHAR2(10));
PROCEDURE get_emp_data
    (emp_data IN OUT emp_data_type);
END;
```

/

> package was created
>   SQL>

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_package AS
  PROCEDURE get_emp_data
 (emp_data IN OUT emp_data_type) IS
  BEGIN
  SELECT empno, ename, to_char(hiredate, 'DD/MON/YY')
  INTO emp_data
  FROM emp
  WHERE empno = emp_data.emp_number;
  END;
```

/

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

> SQL> show error;
>   Errors for PACKAGE BODY EMP_PACKAGE:
>   LINE/COL ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 9/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
>            one of the following:
>            begin end function package pragma procedure form

can any one help on this error

Answer (score 1):

Change `END;` to `END get_emp_data`; and then add `END emp_package;`

The idea is that you are indicating that the first line ends the definition of that procedure, not the body itself, while the second line indicates the end of the package body definition.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you have added **END** wherever you have to.